# Peer Pressure Badge not awarded when somebody else voted to delete my answer

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, badges, peer-pressure-badge

I wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8705248/544050) which was voted down to -3. I then deleted that answer, but I got no badge, yet.
I think that happened because the answer was voted to be deleted by a second user.

> deleted by SecondUser, rekire 22 mins ago

Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: Sometimes it takes a little while for badges to show up.

Comment: That happened 3 hours ago. No changes yet.

Comment: I suspect it may be because the previous vote to delete caused your deletion to just count as a "vote", instead of you deleting it. That's my guess because it's gone past the next UTC date, and still not happened.

Comment: @AndrewBarber, this should be an answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting with the next build we'll change how some back-end data is recorded on PostHistory - I manually corrected your case to have the same behavior, you'll see the badge on the next run.

Specifically, when an owner's "binding" vote is invoked to delete or undelete (when that vote *alone* is enough to cause the action, e.g. not reversing a community decision) we'll record that as the only voter - since that's effectively what happened.  Also, it simplifies many checks downstream, including ones in this badge.