# Can a Stack Overflow admin grant badges to users?

Tags: support, badges

I am aware it is possible for administrators to delete badges if needed. Is the reverse possible - can an admin grant badges if needed?

A situation where this could be relevant is that a badge was not awarded due to a bug.

Comment: [Not a robot](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot) probably.

Comment: If you think that a bug stopped you from getting a badge, you should report it here so that it can be fixed for everyone. But it’s far more likely that you’re just misunderstanding what the badge requires; some of them are a little unintuitive.

Comment: Someone with database access should be able to do that and anything else technically speaking.

Answer (score 20):

The only badge we have a tool for manual awarding is Not a Robot. We cannot and would not award any other badge manually.

If there was a bug that prevented an award from going out, simply fixing the bug is the only solution. Badges are not awarded on the basis of "when it happens" like in video games - rather, we run a query on a schedule that looks for all users who are currently eligible to receive a given badge and haven't yet received it, and award them based on that query.

Comment: When would the *census* badge need manual awarding? Isn’t it done automatically?

Comment: @Daniil It is now. We didn't use it at all this past survey. It was originally built when the badge was first introduced and there were a lot of bugs.

Comment: Re *"we run a query..."*: The reverse is not always true ([or ever](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58389/why-are-badges-kept-even-if-pertinent-action-is-reversed)?) (removing badges no longer eligible for).

Answer (score 7):

While SE staff won't directly award badges to users, sometimes they will intervene to make a badge be auto awarded, e.g. see [this case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120100/152859). In that case there was a bug/oversight causing a badge to not be awarded, so the developer manually changed the condition of the specific user so the badge could be awarded.